# Android Webview loading issues

Tags: java, android, webview

I am trying to load the ews web pages of my HP printer and page is loaded after finished the onPageFnished () event.  The pageFinished event will fire before the page completely loaded. I need to show the progress ring until web pages finished.

Notice that, The last event getting from the WebView is that onLoadResource (). But I don't know the what is the next event after loadView.

Please help to suggest better approaches to solving this issue
Using android version kitkat.

Thanks,
AK

Comment: Since you are using javascript please post your Android code as a code snippet. Thanks.

Comment: Could it be that there is JS running on the page, working hard to put the UI together for you? In that case, you could figure out what is the last element inserted in the page and then check for it periodically. Then hide the progress ring when ready.

Comment: I'm not sure if Android provides an onPageFinished() event in JavaScript.